# Perl6: implicit and explicit import

Tags: import, raku

Is it possible to write a module in a way that when the module is `use`d with no explicit import all subroutines are imported and when it is `use`d with explicit import only theses explicit imported subroutines are available?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6
use v6;
use Bar::Foo;

# all subroutines are imported
sub-one();
sub-two();
sub-three();
```

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6
use v6;
use Bar::Foo :sub-one, :sub-two;

sub-one();
sub-two();
# sub-three not imported
```

Comment: Do you (@sid_com) understand my queued edit to your question (s/export/import/) as explained in my answer (Export ≠ Import) below? Do you agree with it?

Comment: @raiph: For me your edit sounds fine (the fond size is a little irritating). I felt uncomfortable in the first place with the "export" but still used it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Give your subs both the special label `:DEFAULT` as well as a dedicated one when exporting, eg

```
unit module Bar;
sub one is export(:DEFAULT, :one) { say "one" }
sub two is export(:DEFAULT, :two) { say "two" }
```

Now, you can import all of them with a plain `use Bar`, or can select specific ones via `use Bar :one`;