# Import simple module

Tags: module, raku

I have a function written in a module file (`.pm`), and want to use it in a Perl6 file (`.pl6`). The two files are in the same folder:

```
C:\Users\Christian\Dropbox\ChristianPrivatefiler\Programmering\Perl6\perlCode
```

I tried to use the answer to [Perl6: implicit and explicit import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36999241/perl6-implicit-and-explicit-import) but my code returned this error:

```
===SORRY!=== Could not find chrmodule1 at line 5 in:
    C:\Users\Christian\Dropbox\ChristianPrivatefiler\Programmering\Perl6\modules
    C:\Users\Christian\.perl6
    C:\rakudo\share\perl6\site
    C:\rakudo\share\perl6\vendor
    C:\rakudo\share\perl6
    CompUnit::Repository::AbsolutePath<84241584>
    CompUnit::Repository::NQP<86530680>
    CompUnit::Repository::Perl5<86530720> [Finished in 0.436s]
```

Here is the `.pm` file, `chrmodule1.pm`:

```
module chrmodule1 {
    sub foo is export(:DEFAULT, :one) {
        say 'in foo';
    }
}
```

Here is the `.pl6` file, `testOfCode3.pl6`:

```
use v6;
use lib 'modules';
use chrmodule1;

foo();
```

- I use this editor: [atom.io](https://atom.io/)
- Here is another solution to the problem that returned the same error
  when I tried it: [perl6maven.com/tutorial/perl6-modules-export](http://perl6maven.com/tutorial/perl6-modules-export)
- The desired result was:

  ```
   in foo [Finished in 0.317s]
  ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second line of `testOfCode3.pl6` should be `use lib 'perlCode';`.

---

You wrote:

> I have a function written in a module file (`.pm`), and want to use it in a Perl6 file (`.pl6`). The two files are in the same folder:

```
C:\Users\Christian\Dropbox\ChristianPrivatefiler\Programmering\Perl6\perlCode
```

So, you've stored the module in a folder called `perlCode`.

When you run `testOfCode3.pl6` you get an error:

```
===SORRY!=== Could not find chrmodule1 at line 5 in:
    C:\Users\Christian\Dropbox\ChristianPrivatefiler\Programmering\Perl6\modules
```

So, the Rakudo Perl 6 compiler looked for `chrmodule` in a folder called `modules`. Why? Because you told it to:

> Here is the `.pl6` file, `testOfCode3.pl6`:

```
use v6;
use lib 'modules';
```

A `use lib ...` statement tells a Perl 6 compiler where to look first for modules. You've added `modules`, so the Rakudo Perl 6 compiler looked in the `modules` folder first.

It didn't find your module there so it continued on, looking [elsewhere](https://docs.perl6.org/language/modules#Finding_Modules). Hence the lines listing `C:\Users\Christian\.perl6` etc.

In the end it never finds your module because your module is in `perlCode` and you haven't told the compiler to look there. (And it refuses to just look in the current directory for solid security reasons.)